# .each() and .map() incorrect iteration. Help me please

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I need help to understand how .each() works. I have some unusual problem when use .each() or .map() functions.

```
<ol>
  <li>
     <div id="line">One</div>
     <div id="arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png"></div>
            <div id="line" class="sec">
                   <select>
                    <option type="null">-- Выберите утверждение--</option>
                    <option type="true">1</option>
                    <option type="false">2</option>
                    <option type="false">3</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div id="line">Two</div>
     <div id="arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png"></div>
            <div id="line" class="sec">
                   <select>
                    <option type="null">-- Выберите утверждение--</option>
                    <option type="false">1</option>
                    <option type="true">2</option>
                    <option type="false">3</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div id="line">Three</div>
     <div id="arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png"></div>
            <div id="line" class="sec">
                   <select>
                    <option type="null">-- Выберите утверждение--</option>
                    <option type="false">1</option>
                    <option type="false">2</option>
                    <option type="true">3</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

When I perform that function

```
function tcheck()  {
  $('li').map(function(index) {
    alert(index)
  });
}
```

Have strange result: alert has called 14 times! 
Why is **$('li').each()** or  **$('li').map()** calculate each  in `<li>` tag?

Help me please.
Best regards, Mikalai.

Comment: for the given html I only get 3 iterations!?

Comment: Dear Yoshi, funny fact, but in each of my browsers I have 14 iterations.

Comment: Is this html the "real" html, or an excerpt?

Comment: This is excerpt
Here is full version 
[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/83881884/source.zip)

Comment: please post the full version on [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com).

Comment: I found because of what did not work
That is "styler" for select

When a switched off this library my function .each() became correctly works.

Answer (score 0):

`$('li')` selects every single `li` element on the page!  Use a more specific selector like the parent of that particular `ol` element.